# Matrix representation of a transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

We have a linear transformation $T: M_{2\times 2}(F) \to F$ by $T(A) = tr(A)$.

We want to compute the matrix representation $[T]$ from $\alpha$ to $\gamma$ coordinates.

$M_{2\times 2}$ has the standard ordered basis "$\alpha$" for a $2\times 2$ matrix.
$F$ has the standard basis "$\gamma$" for a scalar.

My understanding is that any matrix $A$ in the space $M_{2\times 2}$ can be represented by the linear combination:

$$a\alpha_1 + b\alpha_2 + c\alpha_3 + d\alpha_4$$

and the $tr(A)$ can be written as:

$$(a+c)\gamma.$$

I'm not sure how to get the matrix representation from this.

Thank you guys so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our linear map is
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
T & : & \mathcal M_{2\times 2}(F) & \to     & F \\
  &   & A                      & \mapsto & \DeclareMathOperator{tr}{tr}\tr(A)
\end{array}
$$
The basis $\alpha$ for $\mathcal M_{2\times 2}(F)$ is
$$
\alpha =
\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\right\}
$$
and the basis $\gamma$ for $F$ is $\gamma=\{1\}$.

Now, note that
$$
\begin{array}{lcr}
T\left(\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\right) & = & 1 \\
T\left(\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\right) & = & 0 \\
T\left(\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\right) & = & 0 \\
T\left(\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\right) & = & 1
\end{array}
$$
This implies that $[T]_\alpha^\gamma$ is the $1\times 4$ matrix
$$
[T]_\alpha^\gamma=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This allows us to interpret trace as matrix multiplication. Note that
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}
=
a\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}+
b\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}+
c\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}+
d\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
which means that relative to $\alpha$ the matrix $A$ can be viewed as the vector
$$
\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}
$$
Hence
$$
\tr(A)=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}
=
a+d
$$

Comment: genius, thank you so much!